# Defining a Class in ES2015, what is the constructor method and why is it essential?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, constructor, ecmascript-6

I am in the process of learning ES2015 and I'm not fully understanding everything about classes. To my understanding you define a class like this:

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and a subclass like this:
(where super() must be invoked to initially run the constructor from the parent class).

```
class subClass extends Parent {
  constructor(name, description, url) {
    // subclass must call super to invoke the parent's constructor method
    super();
  }
}
```

What exactly is the constructor method, why is it important, and why does a parents constructor needs to be invoked when creating an instance of a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new instance of a class, the constructor method will be called with the arguments you passed through. In this function, you put any code to construct the instance of your class, like initializing properties.

```
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  sayHi(){
    alert(`${this.name} says hello!`);
  }
}

let person = new Person('Jerry');//this param will be send to the constructor method
person.sayHi();
```

The result of this code will be an alert saying "Jerry says hello!".
Although, the constructor method is not required. The following code will work too.

```
class Person{
  sayHi(){
    alert("Someone says hello!");
  }
}
let person = new Person();
person.sayHi();
```

In case you have a subclass, you might want to call the constructor method of the parent class. This is also not required, but in most cases will be done.

```
class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  sayHi(){
    alert(`${this.name} says hello!`);
  }
}

class SophisticatedPerson extends Person{
  constructor(name){
    super(name);//this will call the constructor method of the Person class
  }
  sayHi(){
    alert(`${this.name} says: Top of the hat to you, sir!`);
  }
  oldSayHi(){
    super.sayHi();//call sayHi of the Person class
  }
}

let person = new SophisticatedPerson('Jerry');
person.sayHi();//calls the overidden sayHi method of SophisticatedPerson class
person.oldSayHi();//calls the oldSayHi of SophisticatedPerson class which calls sayHi of Person class
```

With 'super' you can call the constructor via 'super()' or any other methods via 'super.methodName()' of the parent class as illustrated above.

Extra notice: if you don't provide a constructor method on your child class, the parent constructor method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor method is the method that's invoked when you construct an object with the `new` keyword. It's used to initialize fundamental properties of your object.

The reason you must call the parent constructor (other than the simple fact that this is how "the language rules" are defined) is that you need to allow the parent class to do its initialization.

These are fairly basic, common concepts in many OOP languages.